# How to get first 3 characters of a textbox's text?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

How do I get the first 3 characters of the text in a textbox?

For example, `textBox1.Text = "HITHEREGUYS"`

When I get the first 3 characters, it should show `HIT`.

Comment: [Don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
string result = textBox1.Text.Substring(0,3);
```

Use Substring

Comment: I changed `SubString` to `Substring`, this is case-sensitive!

Comment: And added result variable... He is newbie.

Comment: will throw exception for text less than 3 characters

Answer (score 1):

Text lower than 3 characters will throw an exception. So check text length first:

```
string result = textBox1.Text.Length <= 3 ? textBox1.Text : textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is basically the way you would get it:

```
LEFT(textbox1.text, 3)
```

Comment: My bad.... you are right. I used LEFT all the time in VB.NET and have never had to use it in C#. I assumed it worked in C# as well.